# Street Regex - how do I match a specific word if it appears after another specific word, but not if it occurs before?

Tags: regex

I'm doing a street name regex and want to match the words:

```
(\bNORTH|\bSOUTH|\bEAST|\bWEST)
```

if they occur after the words

```
(\bSTREET|\bAVENUE)
```

... plus 10 other street designations (like LANE, DRIVE, etc which I won't include here)

I don't want to match them if they occur before the street designation, because I want to match the entire street name like so:

```
BOB STREET - Matches "BOB STREET"
BOB STREET WEST - Matches "BOB STREET WEST"
WEST BOB STREET - *** Matches "WEST BOB STREET" ***
NORTH BOB STREET WEST - *** Matches "NORTH BOB STREET WEST" ***
```

Currently, I have an extremely long regex that looks something like this:

```
[0-9].*?((\bSTREET (\bWEST|\bEAST|\bNORTH|\bSOUTH)|\bSTREET)|(\bAVENUE (\bWEST|\bEAST|\bNORTH|\bSOUTH)|\bAVENUE))
```

which gets extremely unwieldy since I have to duplicate WEST, EAST, NORTH, SOUTH once for each of the 15+ street designations.

Is there a way to shorten this to match the street designation and the compass directions - only if they appear after the street designation  - without having to duplicate the compass direction regex after each street designation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a set amount of options followed by a set amount of options that just looks like two OR sets to me. So you should split your options differently. See below how you can avoid copying them every time.

```
(STREET|AVENUE)[\s](NORTH|SOUTH|EAST|WEST)?
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize there was an optional ability that could be used like that. This is exactly what I needed! Thanks!